# Uniq join 3 tables with relationship table not uniq

Tags: postgresql, join, performance, duplication, performance-tuning

I am using Postgres.

I have 3 tables:

```
table_1
  id

table_1_2
  table_1_id, table_2_id

table_2
  id
```

The problem is the relationship table `table_1_2` is not uniq.

I.e., `table_1_2` will have the same tuples multiple times:

```
{1,1}, {1,1}, {1,1}, {1,1}, {1,1}, {1,2}, {1,2}, {1,2} etc.
```

Is there a way to join the `table_1` and `table_2` using `table_1_2`, but with only uniq result?

Currently, I will get all the repeated items as from the relationship table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *many* ways. Here is one (should be a fast variant to retrieve all rows):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN  (
    SELECT DISTINCT table_1_id, table_2_id
    FROM   table1_2
    ) t1_2 ON t1_2.table_1_id = t1.id
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1_2.table_2_id;
```

Why not remove the duplicates permanently? And add a `UNIQUE` constraint ...

Comment: thank you. I am planning to remove duplicates and add unique constraint.